# xml parsing for nested fields

Tags: python, xml

I have XML like this: (this is the soup variable)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<results>
 <status code="ok">
 </status>
 <principal-list>
  <principal account-id="1013353221" has-children="false" is-hidden="false" is-primary="false" principal-id="1013353225" training-group-id="" type="user">
   <name>
    First Last
   </name>
   <login>
    first.last
   </login>
   <email>
    first.last@domain.com
   </email>
   <display-uid>
    first.last
   </display-uid>
  </principal>
  <principal account-id="1013353221" has-children="false" is-hidden="false" is-primary="false" principal-id="1115269931" training-group-id="" type="user">
   <name>
    First Last
   </name>
   <login>
    first.last
   </login>
   <email>
    first.last@domain.com
   </email>
   <display-uid>
    first.last
   </display-uid>
  </principal>
 </principal-list>
</results>
```

I've tried this code:

```
loginlist = [el.string for el in soup.findAll('login')]
for entry in loginlist:
    print entry
```

It returns:

```
first.last
```

for each of the users.

I want to also find the `principal-id` for the nested `login`

My output would look like:

```
`'first.last', '1013353225'`
`'first.last', '1115269931'`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the `<principal>` elements instead:

```
for principal in soup.findAll('principal'):
    login = principal.find('login')
    if login is None:
        continue
    print principal['principal-id'], login.string
```

Comment: Thank you! Change `account-id` to `principal-id` for posterity's sake.

Comment: There you go; the `principal-id` attributes were 'beyond the fold', so to speak and I thus picked the wrong attribute. :-)